# how to use docker buildx pushing image to registry use http protocol？

Tags: docker, build, multiarch

I want to build a multi-arch image and push it to my private registry. However, I got an error

> "failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to do
> request: Head
> https://10.7.121.15/v2/daocloud/multiarch-example/blobs/sha256:4c1976b440416ed5a170b2faf49c05af8f298f7afb07ff1f775b7b1ee7574042:
> x509: cannot validate certificate for 10.7.121.15 because it doesn't
> contain any IP SANs"

when I run command

> "docker buildx build  --platform
> linux/arm/v7,linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64  --tag
> 10.7.121.15/daocloud/multiarch-example:latest  -f multi-arch.dockerfile . --push"

so how to solve it or how to use http protocol pushing image?

Comment: Did you able to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Try passing a [config file](https://github.com/docker/buildx#--config-file) with `http: true`. See [this comment](https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/94#issuecomment-534831828) for more details. E.g.

```
[registry."10.7.121.15"]
  http = true
  insecure = true
```

Answer (score 2):

The [@BMitch answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411302/2039203) have solved the issue, but I want to add more details on how to achieve this.

You need to build builder image with the mentioned config. So after creating the config (e.g. `buildkitd.toml`):

```ini
[registry."10.7.121.15"]
  http = true
  insecure = true
```

you should run the following commands:

```bash
docker buildx rm mybuilder
docker buildx create --name mybuilder --config ./buildkitd.toml --use
docker buildx inspect --bootstrap

docker buildx build ...
```

You can omit the first line if you don't need to clean up previously created builder.

Comment: This does work for me, but isn't there a way to be backward compatible with `docker build` without explicit call to `buildx` and first creating a builder?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a builder like this:

```
docker buildx create --name ci-builder --driver-opt network=host --use --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure'
```